# How can I disable S/MIME signing/encryption for Mail on iOS?

Tags: ios, email, settings, smime

I would like to deactivate S/MIME signing and encryption in Mail on iOS (latest version 16.3.1) as I no longer use it. In Settings > Mail > Accounts > [my account] > Account > Advanced, I see at the bottom two options for S/MIME signing and encryption that can, however, not be deactivated (see screenshots). If I recall correctly, there seemed to have been a third option in the advanced settings, and that was whether to use S/MIME at all. That option is not visible in my settings however. Any help with this is much appreciated

[image: Advanced Settings showing the S/MIME options]
[image: S/MIME signing cannot be turned off]
[image: S/MIME encryption cannot be turned off]

Comment: Without certificate it won't be able to sign/encrypt mails anyway. Does the lack of a certificate cause issues (e.g. warnings when sending mails)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed I get warnings both for composing messages (no cert found) and for sending (do you want to send without encryption?). I didn‘t see an option to deactivate S/MIME altogether for this account, though. Thanks for any hints!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot deactivate signing and encrypting, then it has probably been configured by a profile.

Search for „profile“ under in your Settings app to find the configuration. You can delete the profile unless it has been protected from removal by a password.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I search for profile (or "Profil" in German) in settings, I only find the settings for "VPN and device configuration" which are empty. Also, I recall having installed the S/MIME certificate myself a long time ago. But I can't seem to be able to delete it anymore... :-/

Comment: We are not speaking of a self-signed certificate, are we? What is displayed if you click (i) at the selected certificate? Is it trusted? And did you try to delete and re-create the mail account?